# In Gradient Boosting over Decision Trees what does it mean to reconstruct the residual

Tags: gradient-descent, boosting

[image: Excerpt from GBDT onarogozhnikov.github]

So I am trying to understand what happens in GBDT and particularly I want to know what it mean to "reconstruct the residual." The way I understand it is that the next tree will use the residual (difference between the target function and the ensemble) as the target loss and try to produce a tree that has a loss that is no greater but ideally less than that loss. Am I getting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i can see why your source is confusing so I would recommend using other textbooks to corroborate what the gradient boost algorithm does. but you have the right idea:

the residuals being referred to are actually called **pseudo-residuals** in gradient boost. To say these are being "reconstructed" is misleading and not an appropriate verb. Pseudo-residuals instead are the errors found at each tree estimation of the target loss-ensemble  loss difference which are iteratively corrected at each subsequent tree.  At the end of each individual run (tree), the "reconstruction" is in fact a correction or adjustment of the previous iteration's/tree's pseudo-residuals.

The goal of GBT is to complete all iterations/trees in sequence so that the final ensemble error is lower than the case where you only ran your (non-ensemble) model once, i.e. minimized the target loss only once via the actual (non-pseudo) **residuals** without iterative corrections.